# PgPool Replication - Directly insert into Master, will it replicate to the Slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgpool

I am looking at PostgreSQL 9.4 Streaming Replication with PgPool for Load Balancing vs. using PgPool replication. Since PgPool replication is statement / middleware based does it mean that if I directly update the Master outside of PgPool it will not replicate? Will PgPool detect that the master and slave are out of sync?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I directly update the Master outside of PgPool it will not replicate?

You are correct.

> Will PgPool detect that the master and slave are out of sync?

Sort of--it can monitor statements and check to see if all servers return the same result depending on configuration settings such as `replication_stop_on_mismatch`.

Overall, pgpool replication is quite crude, you ought to use the built-in streaming replication feature unless you have a really good reason otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I set this up and did some basic testing. With only pgpool replication I was able to insert directly into master and it did not get replicated to the slave. I also did not receive any pgpool errors after the sequences went out of sync. I did not try the 'replication_stop_on_mismatch' but I think I will stick to postgresql streaming replication with WAL archiving.